# Convert an object into an array of objects, each containing one of the original object's properties and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I have an object like this:

```
var obj = { foo: function() { ... }, bar: function() { ... }, baz: 10 };
```

I want to convert it to this using vanilla ECMAScript 3 Javascript:

```
[ 
    { name: "foo", value: function() { ... } }, 
    { name: "bar", value: function() { ... } }, 
    { name: "baz", value: 10 }
]
```

How can I do this?

Note: It has to work on IE8.

Comment: just b\\putting a box i.e var arrayOfObjects = [obj] should do the work. Sorry if not relevant.

Comment: @kcube You can't do that - it would make an _Array_ of _length `1`_ with the first item as your whole starting object; i.e. if you tried `arrayOfObjects[1]; // undefined` which is not desired behaviour

Comment: oops i know that. Just got clear with op's question. In that case, for..in should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop will do the trick, it's been around since *ECMAScript 1*.

```
function o2a(o) {
    var arr = [],
        k;
    for (k in o) {
        arr.push({'name': k, 'value': o[k]});
    }
    return arr;
}

// Now can do

var obj = { foo: function() { /* ... */ }, bar: function() { /* ... */ }, baz: 10 };
o2a(obj);
// [
//    {name:"foo", value: function.. },
//    {name:"bar", value: function.. },
//    {name:"baz", value: 10}
// ]
```

Comment: Does `for..in` work in IE8? Can it also be done with a classical `for(var i = 0; i < whatever; i++)` loop?

Comment: for..in works in IE 8. using a 'classical' loop would not work (unless all of your keys were numbers, which clearly they are not)

Comment: Another option you have is that you can always re-implement much of _ES5_ in browsers that don't support it by using a shim or polyfill. I don't see any other way but using `for..in` to get the keys of an _Object_ below _ES5_ though

Answer (score 1):

For future readers who don't need IE 8 support:

use `map` with `Obect.keys()`:

```
myArr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) { return {name: key, value: obj[key]} } );
```

Comment: No, I did not see that requirement. Did you just add that in?

Comment: No, I just added the IE8 clarification. The ECMAScript 3 requirement was there from the start.

Comment: sorry about that. Go with @Paul S. answer